# Line of javascript is being skipped and causing an error below in code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-debugging

I am running the visual studio 2010 debugger to try and debug a javascript script, and it skips over this line:

```
var selectedStatus = "assigned"
```

and then later throws an error when trying to use selectedstatus because it never created and assigned into the variable.

Does anyone have any idea why it would be skipping over this line? Thanks.

Comment: Not without seeing the previous line. But maybe a missing semicolon? Or is it a capitalization issue: selectedstatus vs. selectedStatus

Comment: It also may be a scope issue.

Comment: Only times I've ever seen anything like that happen, it's been the browser caching an older version of the script so that when you're stepping through in VS, you're not seeing the true version of the script that the browser is trying to run.

Comment: Use Firebug to debug Javascript. You can set breakpoints, and step into the code etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your source is out of sync with what's being executed and it just "seems" like it's skipping over that line, while the code that's actually being executed has empty line on that line number.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it needs `;` at the end of the line?

ASI automatically inserts a semicolon if it can, but if the next line starts with a parenthese or a square bracket, it's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons makes it possible to write multiple statements on one line, so they are optional.

Answer (score 0):

There is no semicolon at the end of the line. Often, automatic semicolon insertion will add one in for you, usually when joining the lines would result in a syntax error. However, it's vaguely possible for the two lines to compile together as well as separately, in which case the code would execute as one step from the point of view of the debugger.